What will happen if we don't have 3 moderator candidates?
I already asked on the election related chat and re-thought this question would rather fit here.
So at the moment (after 2 days) we have two candidates for the three open moderator positions.
We all hope there will be more candidates once the deadline comes closer and people see there's no real "competition".
But let's assume none will take the decision and candidate and we stay with two candidates for three open moderator positions.
Now my questions:

Will we skip both primary and election phase and just make the candidates moderators?
Will the nomination phase be expanded?
Will the graduation be taken back and the site will stay in beta for a "little longer"?
Will the current moderators pro tempore automatically be made full moderators to fill the gaps until the next election?


Option 5 - "Will StackExchange start offering free trips to Aruba in exchange for moderation?" :) just kidding.

Note that even if we have 3 moderator candidates, the elections are still not necessary since there are 3 positions to fill. We need at least 4 candidates.

only one more and we're good :)

We currently have 3 candidates, and we just need one more to have more candidates than moderator slots. There is always the option of having a "dummy" candidate, as mentioned in one of the responses to this question on Meta.Money.SE (thx, @HomegrownTomato)
